# Finding distinct numbers in queue using java

Tags: java, algorithm, queue

I want to find distinct numbers in a queue but I can't use anything but a queue such as an array or etc.

Here is my code:

```
    Queue distinct = new Queue(10);
    Queue distincttemp1 = new Queue(10);
    
    int count=0;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    boolean flag=true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int x = rnd.nextInt(9);
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        distinct.enqueue(x);
    }
    System.out.println("");
```

I couldn't find a solution finding how many numbers are repeated except adding every each number to a queue. It should be simple with a few loops. Can you help me find an algorithm?

Input and output should be like this:

> Queue: 4 8 5 8 4 3 2 8

> Output: 5

Answer (score 1):

**You can use Queue and keep track of distinct numbers using HashSet because sets do not allow duplicate values.**

```
        Queue<Integer> distinct = new LinkedList<>();
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet();
        Random random = new Random();
        int number;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            number = random.nextInt(9);
            System.out.print(number+" ");
            distinct.add(number);
            set.add(number);
        }
        System.out.println("Distinct "+set.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, your numbers are between `0` and `8`. That means that a single `Integer` variable is more than enough to mark an occurrence of any of your numbers (we need only `9` bits for that).

## Explanation

### Keep track of distinct values

If a value `x` is generated, then an `x`th bit in the binary representation of the "marker" variable is set to `1`.

```
int marker = 0; 
...
        int x = random.nextInt(9);
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        marker |= (1 << x);
...
```

### Number of distinct values

Then, once the loop is complete, number of set bits in the `marker` corresponds to the number of different values generated in the loop.

```
...
System.out.println(Integer.bitCount(marker));  
...
```

## Full Code

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int marker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int x = random.nextInt(9);
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        marker |= (1 << x);
        queue.add(x);
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + Integer.bitCount(marker));
```

> 4 7 1 4 0 1 4 0 7 8
>
> 5